# JS. Return function in object function return

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have two objects with functions inside. And first works perfect, but second return error than "helper.calc.add is not a function". Whats wrong?

For example first:

```
var calc = (function () {
    var add;
    var remove;

    // some functions add and remove...

   return {
    add: add,
    remove: remove
  }
})();

calc.add(1);
```

And second:

```
var helper = (function () {
   return {
        calc: function () {
           var add;
           var remove;

           // some functions add and remove...

           return {
              add: add,
              remove: remove
          }
       }
  }
})();

helper.calc.add(1);
```

In console:

```
1
Uncaught TypeError: helper.calc.add is not a function
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pk4tsnnt/

Comment: `helper.calc` is a `function`, not `object`...Try `helper.calc().add(1);`

Comment: You probably meant to immediately invoke the function `calc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helper.calc` is a `function`, not `object`

Invoke the `function` to access the property of the object returned by function.

```js
var handler = 1;
var calc = (function() {
  var add;
  var remove;
  if (handler > 0) {
    add = function(a) {
      console.log(a++);
    };
    remove = function(a) {
      console.log(a--);
    };
  } else {
    add = function(a) {
      console.log(a += 2);
    };
    remove = function(a) {
      console.log(a -= 2);
    };
  }
  return {
    add: add,
    remove: remove
  }
})();

var helper = (function() {
  return {
    calc: function() {
      var add;
      var remove;
      if (handler > 0) {
        add = function(a) {
          a++;
        };
        remove = function(a) {
          a--;
        };
      } else {
        add = function(a) {
          a += 2;
        };
        remove = function(a) {
          a -= 2;
        };
      }
      return {
        add: add,
        remove: remove
      }
    }
  }
})();

calc.add(1);
helper.calc().add(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have *`modified`* your *console.log* to show the end result. You were
>   wrongly interpreting the `calc` as `object`, it is a `function`. 
>   Second is
>   the ES6 approach you can use to return the object from a function

It will restructure the add and remove to object which is reverse to destructuring in ES6.

```
return { add, remove }
```

is equivalent to

```
 return { add : add, remove: remove }
```

```js
var handler = 1;

var calc = (function () {
 var add;
    var remove;
      
   if (handler > 0) {
      add = function (a) {
         console.log('calc add ' , ++a);
     } ;
    remove = function (a) {
      console.log(a--);
    };
  } else {
    add = function (a) {
      console.log(a += 2);
    };
    remove = function (a) {
      console.log(a -= 2);
    };
  }

  return { add, remove }

})();

var helper = (function () {
 return {
   calc: function () {
     var add;
      var remove;
      
      if (handler > 0) {
       add = function (a) {
         console.log('Helper calc add ', ++a);
        };
        remove = function (a) {
         a--;
        };
      } else {
       add = function (a) {
         a += 2;
        };
        remove = function (a) {
         a -= 2;
        };
      }
      
      return { add , remove }
      
    }
  }
})();

calc.add(1)
helper.calc().add(1)
```